# Can I use wsHttpBinding along with webHttpBinding in WCF service?

Tags: wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

I have a custom username-password WCF service that needs to be called by Windows client (Winforms application) as well as by Web client (html/aspx page). I have two endpoints declarations in web.config but, to make it work, I have to comment one of them and so, only the client type, associated with that un-commented endpoint, can access the service. If I un-commment that, and comment the other one, other client can access it. I can't keep both of them and so I can't access it with both types of clients.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Behavior1" name="BeST.Service.Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BeST.Service.IService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
     contract="BeST.Service.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

just as the code shows, I need to use both endpoints (above two endpoints) if I want to make this service work for both clients OR, if there's another way to have it done, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving the same address to both endpoints. Try to give another relative address to one of your endpoints and it should work.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Behavior1" name="BeST.Service.Service">
  <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BeST.Service.IService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"></endpoint>
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
    contract="BeST.Service.IService" />
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the this "address" is the issue but I couldn't figure out how to use it if I change it to some value. It works now!